# How do I call the C functions correctly from ARM assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I've been having trouble being able to call C functions headers defined in Q15.s. The functions are coded in assembly, and their headers are stored in Q15.h coded in C. I'm trying to use said functions in CelsiusFahrenheit.s, described below.

In Q15.s, the functions work perfectly. When I debug test_CelsiusFahrenheit I'll get an error saying it's a bad instruction to every line of C code in the file with the function headers.

```
./includes/Q15.h: Assembler messages:
./includes/Q15.h:19: Error: bad instruction `typedef int Q15'
./includes/Q15.h:46: Error: bad instruction `extern Q15 add_Q15(Q15 num1,Q15 num2,unsigned char*overflow)'
./includes/Q15.h:56: Error: bad instruction `extern Q15 sub_Q15(Q15 num1,Q15 num2,unsigned char*overflow)'
./includes/Q15.h:66: Error: bad instruction `extern Q15 mul_Q15(Q15 num1,Q15 num2,unsigned char*overflow)'
./includes/Q15.h:76: Error: bad instruction `extern Q15 div_Q15(Q15 num1,Q15 num2,unsigned char*overflow)'
make: *** [build/CelsiusFahrenheit.o] Error 1
```

This is the Makefile I'm using

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
# options for code generation    
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
ARCH    := -march=armv5te -mlittle-endian
INCL    := -I./includes
ASFLAGS := $(ARCH) $(INCL) -g
CCFLAGS := -Wall -gdwarf-3 -O0 $(ARCH) $(INCL)
LDFLAGS := -z max-page-size=0x8000

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# make commands
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
libQ15.a: build/Q15.o
    arm-none-eabi-ar -rs libQ15.a build/Q15.o

build/Q15.o: sources/Q15.s includes/Q15.h
    arm-none-eabi-as $(ASFLAGS) -c sources/Q15.s -o build/Q15.o

build/CelsiusFahrenheit.o: sources/CelsiusFahrenheit.s includes/Q15.h
    arm-none-eabi-as $(ASFLAGS) -c sources/CelsiusFahrenheit.s -o build/CelsiusFahrenheit.o

build/test_CelsiusFahrenheit.o: tests/test_CelsiusFahrenheit.c includes/Q15.h \
                    includes/CelsiusFahrenheit.h
    arm-none-eabi-gcc $(CCFLAGS) -c tests/test_CelsiusFahrenheit.c -o build/test_CelsiusFahrenheit.o


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# test making commands
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

test_CelsiusFahrenheit.elf : build/test_CelsiusFahrenheit.o build/CelsiusFahrenheit.o \
                    includes/Q15.h
    arm-none-eabi-ld $(LDFLAGS) build/test_CelsiusFahrenheit.o build/CelsiusFahrenheit.o \
                    tests/startup.o -o test_CelsiusFahrenheit.elf



#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
# clean commands
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
clean : 
    @rm -fv build/*
    @rm -fv *.elf


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# debug commands
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
debug : test_CelsiusFahrenheit.elf
    arm-eabi-insight test_CelsiusFahrenheit.elf &
```

This is Q15.h

```
#ifndef Q15_H
#define Q15_H


typedef int Q15;


#define MAKE_Q15(real)  (int)((real)*(1<<15)+(real<0?-0.5:0.5)) 


#define MASK_SIGN   0x80000000  /* bit 31:      signe */
#define MASK_INT    0x7FFF8000  /* bits 30..15: part entera */
#define MASK_FRAC   0x00007FFF  /* bits 14..0:  part fraccionària */



/* Arithmetic operations based on Fixed Point 1:16:15*/

extern Q15 add_Q15(Q15 num1, Q15 num2, unsigned char * overflow);

extern Q15 sub_Q15(Q15 num1, Q15 num2, unsigned char * overflow);

extern Q15 mul_Q15(Q15 num1, Q15 num2, unsigned char * overflow);

extern Q15 div_Q15(Q15 num1, Q15 num2, unsigned char * overflow);


#endif /* Q15_H */
```

This is Q15.s, where the functions are defined

```
.bss
        .align 2
    q: .space 4
    r: .space 4

.text
        .align 2
        .arm
        .global add_Q15

add_Q15:
    push {r3, r4, lr}

    mov r4, #0      @; S'estableix que no hi ha overflow en el princpi
    adds r3, r0, r1 @; Es sumen els dos números i s'actualitzen els flags (el flag de overflow s'actualitza aquí)
    bvs .LifOv1
    b .LelseOv1

    .LifOv1:
        mov r4, #1  @; S'estableix que sí hi ha overflow a variable local
    .LelseOv1:

    strb r4, [r2]   @; S'estableix si hi ha overflow a la variable passada per referència
    mov r0, r3      @; Es retorna la suma
    pop {r3, r4, pc}

sub_Q15:
    push {r3, r4, lr}

    mov r4, #0      @; S'estableix que no hi ha overflow en el princpi
    subs r3, r0, r1 @; Es resten els dos números i s'actualitzen els flags (el flag de overflow s'actualitza aquí)
    bvs .LifOv2
    b .LelseOv2

    .LifOv2:
        mov r4, #1  @; S'estableix que sí hi ha overflow a variable local
    .LelseOv2:

    strb r4, [r2]   @; S'estableix si hi ha overflow a la variable passada per referència
    mov r0, r3      @; Es retorna la resta
    pop {r3, r4, pc}


mul_Q15:
    push {r3-r7, lr}

    mov r5, #0

    smull r3, r4, r0, r1
    mov r3, r3, lsr #15         @; Es prepara el resultat de la multiplicació que s'ha de retornar
    orr r3, r4, lsl #17     
    mov r4, r4, asr #15         @; Es desplacen tants bits com part fraccionària 
                                @; hi ha cap a l'esquerra per a poder veure el bit de signe

    ldr r6, =0x80000000         @; S'estableix la màscara
    and r7, r4, r6              @; R7 = R4 && MASK_SIGN

    .Lif3:
        cmp r3, #0              @; Es mira si el resultat de la multiplicació és negatiu
        bge .Lelse3
        .Lif4:
            cmp r7, r6          @; Es compara el registre amb bit de signe(passat per la màscara), amb la màscara
            beq .Lendif3
            mov r5, #1          @; Si R7 != R6, llavors hi ha hagut overflow
        .Lendif4:
    .Lelse3:
        cmp r4, #0              @; Si el registre amb el bit de signe(passat per la màscara) 
        beq .Lendif3            @; és diferent de 0, significarà que hi ha hagut overflow
        mov r5, #1
    .Lendif3:

    mov r0, r3                  @; Es retorna el resultat del producte
    strb r5, [r2]               @; S'estableix la variable passada per referència overflow
    pop {r3-r7, pc}
```

CelsiusFahrenheit.s, where I'm trying to use the functions

```
.include "Q15.i"
.include "Q15.h"

.text
        .align 2
        .arm


    .global Celsius2Fahrenheit
Celsius2Fahrenheit:
        push {r1-r3, lr}
        ldr r1, =58982          @; 9/5 * 2^15 = 58.982
        bl mul_Q15              @; r0 = r0 * r1
    
        ldr r1, =1048576        @; r0 = r1 + 1.048.576 | 1.048.576 = 32 * 2^15
        bl sum_Q15  
        pop {r1-r3, pc}



    .global Fahrenheit2Celsius
Fahrenheit2Celsius:
        push {r1-r3, lr}
        ldr r1, =1048576        @; 32 * 2^15 = 1.048.576
    
        bl sub_Q15              @; r0 = r0 - r1 
    
        ldr r1, =18204          @; 5/9 * 2^15 = 18.204
        bl mul_Q15              @; r1 = r0 * 5/9
    
        pop {r1-r3, pc}
```

This is Q15.i

```
MASK_SIGN = 0x80000000              @; bit 31:      sign
MASK_INT  = 0x7FFF8000              @; bits 30..15: integer part
MASK_FRAC = 0x00007FFF              @; bits 14..0:  fractional part
```

Comment: You're including a C header into an assembly file. Why?

Comment: If I don't, I'll get an error when debugging saying that add_Q15, sub_Q15 and mul_Q15 are undefined references. How should I call them then?

Comment: What do you mean "when debugging"?

Comment: @JanTorresRodríguez you did not get to the stage where you can debug anything. You try to assemble `.h` files and it will not work

Comment: GAS doesn't need any `.extern` directive or anything.  An undefined symbol is assumed extern by default, and GAS doesn't need or want a prototype of any form.  (And certainly not in C syntax).  `bl mul_Q15` is correct, if you link with a `.o` that does define that symbol (e.g. from C compiler-generated code.)

Comment: You include `Q15.h` into the .s file. This is wrong. And what is `Q15.i`? Anyway: +1 because the questions is well written and well formatted which is rare for people with little rep.

Comment: @Siguza For debugging, I just mean running test_CelsiusFahrenheit.c, which acts as a test suite.

Comment: Well yeah because these lines of code aren't valid assembly code. What were you expecting by giving C code to the assembler?

Comment: @JanTorresRodríguez you should show `Q15.i` for completness.

Comment: @PeterCordes How should I link them to do as you say? Should I add build/Q15.o into build/CelsiusFahrenheit.o or test_CelsiusFahrenheit.elf?

Comment: @JanTorresRodríguez what happens if you remove `.include "Q15.h"` from `CelsiusFahrenheit.s`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky It will print out this error `build/CelsiusFahrenheit.o: In function Celsius2Fahrenheit':
c:\URV\FonCompus\PracticaARM\3_LibQ15/sources/CelsiusFahrenheit.s:34: undefined reference to sum_Q15'` I don't know why it's not showing now, but it'd show the same exact error for both sub_Q15 and mul_Q15

Comment: The problem is you don't link with `libQ15.a` (or `Q15.o`) in the recipe with `arm-none-eabi-ld`